# Placeholder image is not loading up properly with cards [ReactJs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, syntax-error

so I'm working on a project that loads up a list of cards that obtains data from an API such as "Id, title, URL and thumbnail URL".

The cards currently load up an image IF a thumbnail URL is provided by the API, but  if no thumbnail URL is provided, then I was wanting to set a placeholder image that will be displayed in it's place. The following image is of how the cards are currently set with + without a thumbnail URL:
[image]

As you can see, there currently is a placeholder image that I have set up, but for some reason, there is an "error" section that loads under the placeholder which means that no image is being provided in the image section. I was wondering how I can go about officially declaring it a placeholder image to use without me having to hard code the image into the card?

The code for the card creation is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../help/HelpCardTwo.css";
import "../help/HelpList";
import Popup from "reactjs-popup";
import placeholder from "../help/placeholder.jpeg";

interface Props {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  deleteProduct: (id: any) => void;
  editProduct: (id: any, title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) => void;
}

interface State {
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
  id: string;
  url: string;
  imageLoading?: boolean;
  tooManyRequests?: boolean;
}

export default class HelpCard extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    url: "",
    id: "",
    title: "",
    imageLoading: true,
    tooManyRequests: false,
    thumbnail: ""
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { url, title, thumbnail } = this.props;
    const id = url.split("/")[url.split("/").length - 2];

    this.setState({
      url,
      id,
      title,
      thumbnail,
      imageLoading: true,
      tooManyRequests: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    const isThumbnail = this.state.thumbnail;
    const adminhelpcard = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <article className="card card--2">
          <div className="card__img">
            {this.state.imageLoading ? <img src={placeholder} style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}></img> : null}
            <img
              className="Sprite"
              onLoad={() => this.setState({ imageLoading: false })}
              onError={() => this.setState({ tooManyRequests: false })}
              src={this.state.thumbnail}
            />
          </div>
```

The code shown is only for the image section of the card and not the rest of it. If anything else is needed then please let me know and I will provide the code.

How can I officially load up the placeholder image while not having the little error square under it?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import a binary file as a variable. For this to work you need to check if your webpack is configured for the same with the proper file loader.
Your **webpack.config.js** should have something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by this? Since I can't seem to find a webpack.config.ts

Comment: What I am trying to say is if you don't have a file loader configured for image files like png, jpeg, gif etc. in your bundling tool you cannot access .jpeg file contents by using a variable.

try using this :

import  * as placeholder from "../help/placeholder.jpeg";

Comment: changing the import to what you've made it gives me the following error from my <img src={placeholder}> as follows: Type 'typeof import("*.jpeg")' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)